# De qual maneira POST difere de PUT ao lidar com URIS já existentes?

Tags: javascript, html, http

Não apenas este site, mas vários outros usam o exemplo de criar um usuário em um website:

```
www.site.com.br/user/id_do_usuario
```

Para elucidar que PUT apenas atualizaria o usuário antigo com os dados inseridos, e POST criaria um novo, ao se requisitar um id já existente. Mas de qual maneira POST lida com a criação de um novo usuário, se as URIS são as mesmas?

Comment: E qual seria o problema de serem as mesmas? Inclusive, tem inúmeras APIs que tem um URL só para várias operações. Quem define como ela vai se comportar é quem escreveu a API. Talvez fosse interessante você [edit] o post e embasar melhor de onde tirou a conclusão que o URI determinaria o comportamento da API, ou restringiria sua funcionalidade de qualquer maneira. Exemplificando de outra forma: eu poderia ter uma API com o caminho `http://nomedosite/x` e fazer todas as operações com POST (deletar usuário, criar, editar, deletar imóvel, etc) apenas mudando os dados enviados.

Comment: @Bacco por exemplo, ao se criar um perfil de usuário baseado no nome definido pelo cliente em um campo de entrada. Não compreendo como usuários diferentes poderiam ter a mesma URI

Comment: Vale lembrar que URL é opaca e não reflete, necessariamente, a lógica da aplicação. Se eu quiser ter em minha API a URL `/batatas` e utilizá-la para enviar um e-mail para o presidente dos EUA no método GET eu poderia.

Comment: abcson justamente, e o que te induziu a pensar que uma coisa tem relação com a outra (o URI com o resultado)?

Answer (score 1):

Uma requisição HTTP é mais do que uma URI, ela inclui cabeçalho e possivelmente uma carga util (o corpo). A maior parte dessa requisição é preenchida automaticamente pelo navegador, mas ela em seu total se parece com isso:

```
GET /docs/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.nowhere123.com
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
```

Como você pode ver, além da URI, o método também é enviado, e portanto o servidor pode tratar a resposta de acordo com a requisição recebida.